# Calling external API only when new data is available

Tags: node.js, api, express, npm

I am serving my users with data fetched from an external API. Now, I don't know when this API will have new data, how would be the best approach to do that using Node, for example?

I have tried setInterval's and node-schedule to do that and got it working, but isn't it expensive for the CPU? For example, over a day I would hit this endpoint to check for new data every minute, but it could have new data every five minutes or more.

The thing is, this external API isn't ran by me. Would the only way to check for updates hitting it every minute? Is there any module that can do that in Node or any approach that fits better?

**Use case 1** : Call a weather API for every city of the country and just save data to my db when it is going to rain in a given city.

**Use case 2** : Send notification to the user when a given Philips Hue lamp is turned on at the time it is turned on without having to hit the endpoint to check if it is on or not.

I appreciate the time to discuss this.

Answer (score 2):

If this external API has no means of notifying you when there's new data, then the only thing you can do is to "poll" it to check for new data.

You will have to decide what an "efficient design" for polling is in your specific application and given the type of data and the needs of the client (what is an  acceptable latency for new data).

You also need to be sure that your service is not violating any terms of service with your polling scheme or running afoul of rate limiting that may deny you access to the server if you use it "too much".

> Would the only way to check for updates hitting it every minute?

Unless the API offers some notification feature, there is no other scheme other than polling at some interval.  Polling every minute is fairly quick.  Do your clients really need information that is less than a minute old?  Or would it really make no difference if the information was as much as 5 minutes old.

For example, in your example of weather, a client wouldn't really need temperature updates more often than probably every 10-15 minutes.

> Is there any module that can do that in Node or any approach that fits better?

No.  Not really.  You'll probably just use some sort of timer (either repeated `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` in a node.js app to repeatedly carry out your API operations.

> Use case: Call a weather API for every city of the country and just save data to my db when it is going to rain in a given city.

Trying to pre-save every possible piece of data from an external API is probably a losing proposition.  You're essentially trying to "scrape" all the data from the external API.  That is likely against the terms of service and will likely also run afoul of rate limits.  And, it's just not very practical.

Instead, you will probably want to fetch data upon demand (when a client requests data for Phoenix, then, and only then, do you start collecting data for Phoenix) and then once a demand for a certain type of data (temperatures in a particular city) is established, then you might want to pre-cache that data more regularly so you can notify clients of changes.  If, after awhile, no clients are asking for data from Phoenix, you stop requesting updates for Phoenix any more until a client establishes demand again.

> I have tried setInterval's and node-schedule to do that and got it working, but isn't it expensive for the CPU? For example, over a day I would hit this endpoint to check for new data every minute, but it could have new data every five minutes or more.

Making a remote network request is not a CPU intensive operation, even if you're doing it every minute.  node.js uses non-blocking networking so most of the time during a network request, node.js isn't doing anything and isn't using the CPU at all.  The only time the CPU would be briefly used is when you first send the API request and then when you receive back the result from the API call and need to process it.

Whether you really need to "poll" every minute depends upon the data and the needs of the client.  I'd ask yourself if your app will work just fine if you check for new data every 5 minutes.

Comment: Got what you mean. I made it work with node-schedule, running it every minute. The thing is that having the information at the time it is provided at the external API makes the experience on my app much better. Maybe the weather example wasn't very similar to what I'm trying to do, but basically I want to notify users with a push notification whenever a condition is met. For example, providing a notification when a given Philips Hue lamp is turned on at the time it is turned on. If I check it every minute, at least we will have seconds of difference, but still have a lot of empty responses.

Answer (score 0):

The method I would use to update would be contained outside of the code in a scheduled batch/powershell/bash file. In windows you can schedule tasks based upon time of day or duration since last run, so what you could do is run a simple command that will kill your application for five minutes, run ***npm update***, and then restart your application before closing the shell.

That way you're staying out of your API and keeping code to a minimum, and if your code is inside that Node package in the update, it'll be there and ready once you make serious application changes or you need to take the server down for maintenance and updates to the low-level code.

This is a light-weight solution for you and it's a method I've used once or twice at my workplace. There are lots of options out there, and if this isn't what you're looking for I can keep looking out for you.

Comment: Interesting approach. I wonder if that would fit in an AWS container too. Got it working with node-schedule and it did fine doing requests every minute on a function. I am worried about not doing heavy work on the processor and, of course, having safer approaches for handling sensitive data that updates over unknown intervals.

Comment: this answer is a bit confusing. wasn't the OP asking about data that is fetched via an external API? I'm not getting how `npm update` fits into this